# roslaunch can not launch node on remote machine

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community!!

Following setup: one Ubuntu 16.04 PC with ros-kinetic and one Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Mate and ros-kinetic.

On each machine there is a lauch-file for some nodes, they are configured to work together. As long as i launch them
manually everything is fine :)

Problem:
Now i merged the two separate launch-file and added the "machine"-tag....
For simplification and debuging, i tried it with the talker and listener from ros-tuorial.
My approach looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="alice" address="alice.emma.lab" env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" />
    <machine name="rosPi" address="rosPi.emma.lab"  env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" />
    <node machine="alice" pkg="dummy" name="talker-alice" type="talker"/>
    <node machine="rosPi" pkg="delault_pkg" name="listener-pi" output="screen" type="listener" /> 
 </launch>
```

But all i get is:

```
....
remote[rosPi.emma.lab-0]: ssh connection created
....
MACHINES
* alice
* rosPi
....
process[talker-alice-6]: started with pid [4155]
[rosPi.emma.lab-0]: launching nodes...
[rosPi.emma.lab-0]: ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.1:11311/
[rosPi.emma.lab-0]: ERROR: cannot launch node of type [delault_pkg/listener-pi]: delault_pkg
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
[rosPi.emma.lab-0]: ... done launching nodes
```

So i checked: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup.
Result: ssh-login with keys, ping, netcat and name resolution works, ROS_HOSTNAME & ROS_MASTER_URI are correct. On both PCs the firewall is down.

But still no chance with the given launch-file :/
Have i missed anything??
Any config, tag or somesing?
I am grateful for any hint!

**EDIT and Solution:**

With the exact path to env-loader for the remote package:

```
<machine name="rosPi" address="ros-rasp-mate.emma.lab"  env-loader="/home/labh/plattform-ros/devel/env.sh" />
```

It works :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286576/roslaunch-can-not-launch-node-on-remote-machine/) by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-26**:
roslaunch xml substitution args (ie: `find` and friends) are evaluated on the machine where `roslaunch` is invoked. This means that if `default_pkg` / your workspace is not in the exact same location as on your desktop, it cannot be started on your Pi.

Can you check?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-26**:
Also: `pkg="delault_pkg"`: is that a typo, or is it really `delault` (and not `default`)?

**Comment by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on 2018-03-26**:
Thank you for your answer!
Yes, default vs delault is a typo in my Question -.-' Sorry for this!
If i understand your comment right, on both machines have to be the default_pkg under the same path?
This is not the case. This package is only on the Pi and not at the desktop, should it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're using the default environment loader, which will only set up the package path for ROS packages that are installed in opt.

You should instead use the environment loader from your remote workspace; there should be an auto-generated environment loader in `devel/env.sh` within your remote catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on 2018-03-26**:
So instead of:

```
<machine name="rosPi" address="rosPi.emma.lab"  env-loader="/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh" />
```

is should be

```
<machine name="rosPi" address="rosPi.emma.lab"  env-loader="/path/to/workspace/devel/env.sh" />
```

?
Thank you for your answer! I will give it a try asap.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-03-26**:
Yes. The exact path will depend on the path to your workspace.

**Comment by [krl101](https://answers.ros.org/users/29382/krl101/) on 2018-03-27**:
Checked!!!
Thank you very much!!

**Comment by [SJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/30818/sj/) on 2018-03-29**:
Met the same problem and it is the reason. Upvote.